# Conectarme a diferentes origenes OLE DB en SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Desde hace varios días estoy tratando de realizar una conexión a la BDD a través del asistente OLE DB en Sql Server Integration Services. Lo que necesito es poder conectarme a distintos servidores para poder hacer una misma consulta pero en todos los servidores a la vez. En una tabla, tengo parámetros que identifican a cada servidor.

¿De que manera puedo acceder a una conexión en todos los servidores para realizar una misma consulta?

Es decir, tengo 40 bases de datos distintas que contienen información de 40 sucursales distintas, lo que no quiero es generar 40 orígenes OLE DB y quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de hacer variable un origen y a través de ese origen se puedan consultar las 40 BDD con la misma consulta SQL.

Lo que estoy haciendo de momento es añadir un foreach y el foreach configurarlo de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los archivos de conexión tienen la siguiente estructura:

**Data Source=136.4.3.7;Initial Catalog=MundoEApp;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;**

En la parte de las variables del foreach tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte de la conexión de inicio la configure a un servidor utilizando la autenticación de Windows y posteriormente modifique la propiedad ConnectionString de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando trato de ejecutar la consulta SQL me manda el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su ayuda por adelantado , saludos.

Comment: Hola Guillermo. Has hecho esta pregunta (de maneras parecidas) 3 veces en 48h. Y las dos veces anteriores ha acabado cerrada por *no esta claro lo que se pregunta* y posteriormente eliminada por ti. En vez de eso, lee [ask] e intenta mejorar el estado de la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Sería bueno que revises [¿Qué debo hacer si nadie contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para casos complejos como estos, SSIS tiene dos componentes: Script Task y Script Component; lo que debes hacer es crear tus conexiones y ejecutar las consultas a través de esto, programando en C# e ir insertando los datos de forma centralizada.

Acá la imagen del componente Script Task y sus configuraciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la casilla ReadOnlyVariables puedes asignar Variables con el nombre de los servidores y las credenciales para conectar; En ReadWriteVariables debes especificar las variables que recibirán el resultado de lo que haces, de forma tal que puedas usarlas en los pasos siguientes de tu ETL.

Por último y un poco más avanzado, en la pestaña Expressions puedes realizar iteraciones automáticas con expresiones a ejecutar.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta aunque sigo sin entender muy bien. Podrías agregar un pequeño ejemplo ?

Comment: En esta pág. redacto cómo hacer un ETL con variables; busca información sobre el Script Component y vas a salir a camino
http://www.bdconsql.com/2017/02/18/etl-incremental-insertando-nuevos-registros-y-actualizando-los-existentes/